# HOW TO FIX: output result generated by domPDF?

Tags: php, dompdf

Hi this is what I'm getting with the domPDF. Is my final result, but obviously I don't want that, I want my page printed in PDF.

I need the file get downloaded in the user browser, not in localhost.

[image]

This is my javascript:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){          
        $.post("converter/converter.php", {strHtml: $(".container-   fluid").html()}, function(data, status){
                alert("Data: " + data);
        });
    });
```

this is my php:

```
<?php
    require_once '../dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;

    $html = $_POST['strHtml'];

    $dompdf = new Dompdf();

    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->output('test.pdf', 'F');
 ?>
```

This is what I want to display in pdf :

[image]

Comment: While technically possible it's going to be more work than just `alert`ing the return from your AJAX call. PDF documents are a binary format and need to be rendered. While most browsers support rendering the PDF content typically has to be the entirety of the page.

Comment: What, exactly, are you seeking to do here? Obviously you want to submit some data to the server and have a PDF document rendered. But why are you doing this through AJAX request? [Is that necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17664966/264628)? An easier method would be to push the content into a hidden variable and submit the form normally.

Comment: ok, how do you submit a <table> with rows <tr> if i dont want o refresh the page???

Comment: You can use your existing method, but instead of ajax populate a hidden form variable with the content and submit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the generated pdf file to disk. You don't need `file_put_content()`. But you pass two parameters to the `->output()` method, like this:

```
$dompdf->output($path_to_new_file, 'F');
```

Comment: it seems is working but is not downloading neather saving the file in the path. Is it possible with ajax??

Comment: $dompdf->output('test.pdf', 'F');

Comment: if its neither saving the file nor downloading it, what makes you think its working?

Comment: what path you've provided? it must be writeable by the web user. Check if it have permissions to write to that particular directory.

Comment: I need the file get downloaded in the user browser, not in localhost

Comment: $dompdf->output('test.pdf', 'F');

Comment: with php, or javascript for that matter, you cannot save file to user's computer, instead what you can do is save the file on server in a publicly accessible directory, and then force the user to save file instead of viewing in browser by setting appropriate response headers.

Comment: The `$dompdf->output()` method is for retrieving the PDF source as a string, which you can then use to put into a file *on the server* using `file_put_contents`. Something along the lines of `file_put_contents('doc.pdf', $dompdf->output());`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit the page as exists in the browser you'll have to capture the content (as you have done) and then, instead of submitting via AJAX request, push that content into a form and submit that form.

```js
$("#submit").click(
  function() {
    $('#strHtml').val($(".container-fluid").html());
    $('#makePdfForm').submit();
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=".container-fluid">
  <p>Some stuff here, rendered dynamically on the client</p>
</div>

<form action="converter/converter.php" method="post" id="makePdfForm">
  <input name="strHtml" id="strHtml" type="hidden" value="">
  <button type="button" id="submit">Make PDF</button>
</form>
```

Then your PHP changes very little:

```
<?php
require_once '../dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$html = $_POST['strHtml'];
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('test.pdf');
?>
```